# How to switch the position or exchange the content of two JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, combobox, jcombobox

I am new to JAVA GUI and faced a problem. The following picture shows the part of GUI where my problem lies.

[image]

I want to achieve that when I click the "click to switch" button, the content of the comboBox will be exchanged. I tried different ways to either exchange the position of the two comboBox or exchange the content of the two ComboBox, but neither worked out.

Following is the part of my code related to this problem.

Class1:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FilePathComboBox implements ActionListener {
    List<String> strings;
    BufferedReader input;
    JComboBox comboBox;
    JPanel jpFilePath;
    JButton testJB;

    public FilePathComboBox(String filePathOfSyncTool) {
        strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileReader fr;

        try {
            fr = new FileReader(filePathOfSyncTool);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            fr = null;
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        input = new BufferedReader(fr);
        try {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                strings.add(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Error, file " + filePathOfSyncTool + 
            "didn't exist.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String[] lineArray = strings.toArray(new String[] {});

        comboBox = new JComboBox(lineArray);
        testJB = new JButton("click to add item");
        testJB.addActionListener(this);
        jpFilePath = new JPanel();
        jpFilePath.add(comboBox);
        jpFilePath.add(testJB);

    }

    public JComboBox getJComboBox(){
        return this.comboBox;
    }

    public void setJComboBox(JComboBox jcb){
        this.comboBox = jcb;
    }

    public JPanel getjpFilePath(){
        return jpFilePath;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String s1 = "E:\\home\\joe\\foo";
        comboBox.insertItemAt(s1, 0);
        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);

    }
}
```

class2:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SwitchComboBox implements ActionListener {
    JPanel switchOverall;
    JButton switchButton;
    FilePathComboBox fpcb;
    FilePathComboBox fpcb2;
    public SwitchComboBox(){
        fpcb = new FilePathComboBox("E:\\pathRecord.txt");
        fpcb2 = new FilePathComboBox("E:\\pathRecord2.txt");
        switchButton = new JButton("click to switch");
        switchOverall = new JPanel();
        switchButton.addActionListener(this);
        switchOverall.add(fpcb.getjpFilePath());
        switchOverall.add(fpcb2.getjpFilePath());
        switchOverall.add(switchButton);
    }

    public JPanel getSwitchOverall(){
        return this.switchOverall;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Here should be the code to switch the content 
        //or position of the two comboBox
        Component[] stringArray = fpcb.getJComboBox().getComponents();
        Component[] stringArray2 = fpcb2.getJComboBox().getComponents();
        fpcb.setJComboBox(new JComboBox());
        for(int i =0; i < stringArray2.length; i++){
            fpcb.getJComboBox().add(stringArray2[i]);
        }
        fpcb2.setJComboBox(new JComboBox());
        for(int i =0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
            fpcb2.getJComboBox().add(stringArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope someone can kindly help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "contents will exchange"? Do you mean that the data held within the comboboxes will swap? If so, simply swap models.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels  Yes, I want the data held within the comboBoxes to be swapped. I am not very familiar with models. Could you give me more details about how to swap models?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean that the data held within the comboboxes will swap? If so, simply swap models:

```
ComboBoxModel model1 = fpcb.getJComboBox().getModel();
ComboBoxModel model2 = fpcb2.getJComboBox().getModel();

fpcb.getJComboBox().setModel(model2);
fpcb2.getJComboBox().setModel(model1);
```